# Referring to vararg function parameters Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, variadic-functions

Is there a way to refer to

**permission.permissionName**

in this code:

```
fun Activity.isPermissionGranted(vararg permission : AppPermission) = (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.permissionName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

As is I am getting "unresolved reference: permissionName" error.

**AppPermission** class signature looks like this:

```
sealed class AppPermission(val permissionName: String,
                           val requestCode: Int,
                           val deniedMessageId: Int,
                           val explanationMessageId: Int) {...}
```

To be honest I am not even sure if using varargs here is a good idea so if it's completely bonkers please correct me.

Basically I am trying to implement grant permission(s) logic for Android > 5.0 and I am not sure how many permissions we're going to end up needing so this is why I thought about using varargs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vararg` is basically just syntactic sugar for creating arrays. Thus, you will need to treat the parameter `permission` like an `Array<AppPermission>`, which means that you might want to do this:

```
fun Activity.isPermissionGranted(vararg permissions : AppPermission) = permissions.all { permission -> (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.permissionName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) }
```

Here, `all` is a function from the standard library that computes a `Boolean` for each value in the array and returns `true` if all those `Boolean`s are `true`.